# How to get maximum value for a list in a data frame in R

Tags: r, string, list, dataframe, stringr

I am trying to create a new column that gets me the maximum value for a list in a data frame. I was wondering how I can create this column called maxvalue from the df$value column i.e., I would like to get the max of that list in the column.

```
  x <- c( "000010011100011111001111111100", "011110", "0000000")
  y<- c(1, 2,3)
 df<- data.frame(x,y)
 library(stringr)
 df$value <- strsplit(df$x, "[^1]+", perl=TRUE)
  # expected output  ( I have tried the following)
 df$maxvalue<- max(df$value) 
  df$maxvalue
   8 
   4
   0
```

Comment: is the output sum of 1's in the string? Also, please clarify on max value, are you comparing it with y field to find the max value?

Comment: It is the max of the continuous series of 1's , for example 10001100111, in this case it will be 3 as the max continuous

Comment: If my answer helped you, please consider accepting it. thnks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this should do the trick

```
df$value <- lapply(lapply(strsplit(as.character(df$x),"[^1]+"), nchar),max)
```

output:

```
> df
                               x y value
1 000010011100011111001111111100 1     8
2                         011110 2     4
3                        0000000 3     0
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplified version of @Daniel O's logic:

```
df$value <- sapply(strsplit(as.character(df$x),"[^1]+"), function(x){max(nchar(x))})
```

Comment: You can simplify slightly more. No need for the `{` and `}` for your function in this case

Comment: @DanielO While you are correct that won't actually have any impact on the input/output or speed of the code.

Answer (score 1):

We can also use `rawToChar` and `charToRaw`

```
sapply(as.character(df$x), function(x) 
      with(rle(charToRaw(x)), max(lengths[as.character(values) == 31])))
```